# How to use .tff font in a Chrome extension?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to CSS, and not sure why this isn't working. I downloaded a .tff font from the web and put it in my css folder right next to popup.css. This is not a content script extension if that makes a difference (this font is used in the popup, and settings pages), and I'm loading my extension by "load unpacked" on chrome extensions.

popup.css

```
@font-face{
 font-family:'digital-7';
 src: url("./digital-7.ttf");
}

.digit {
  font: digital-7;
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 'bold';
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

The element in question in one of my React component files:

```
<div className="digit">{this.state.seconds}</div>
```

I've tried adding `type="text/css"` to the div, and also tried committing the `url()` as I'm not sure why I would need that, but those didn't work either. Does this have something to do with the manifest file? I don't even get any errors that I can see.

Comment: [This should help](https://medium.com/@charlesdouglasosborn/how-to-add-style-and-webfonts-to-a-chrome-extension-content-script-css-47d354025980)

Comment: I tried adding `"web_accessible_resources": ["popup.css", "digital-7.ttf"]` to the manifest and changed the url to be `url(chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/digital-7.ttf)`, but it still doesn't work. The .ttf file is in the same folder as popup.css, but I build my files through `npm run build`, so in the build folder everything is in it without any inner folders, so my paths should be correct here. That article and everything I can find online are in regards to content scripts, which my extension doesn't have so I wonder if the problem has to do with that.

Comment: popup.css doesn't need to be in the build folder to work so I also tried leaving it and the digital-7.ttf out of it, but that doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a simple mistake that I needed to use `font-family: digital-7` instead of just `font: digital-7`.